# how this works ? Copy figma component from website and paste it in my own file

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the example site doing the same : https://ui-kit.co/explore

How this uikit.co/explore works :

When you hover on any file it will show a copy button, once you copy then you can directly paste it into your Figma artboard, how does this work, and How can I implement it on my site?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't javascript, html, css. But you just copy and paste it into a *figma* document. It works using the clipboard. You can't paste it into a website. But if you want, you can do all kinds of things with [clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard) in JavaScript.

The content of the clipboard whilst copying can be viewed in https://evercoder.github.io/clipboard-inspector/ for example. But it's a little cryptic in this case.

Another example, btw, is WordPress block editor which allows you to copy block from place to place. The data of the block/clipboard is just an HTML so can easily be moved around. You can use copy/paste JSON to pass data into/from your site utilizing [onpaste](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpaste.asp) event.

[image: Figma copy paste]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response and how I can Implement it on my site like this ?